# Should I be able to answer my own question within 12 hours?

Tags: discussion

I feel there's possibly a subtle loophole that we might need to block.

Do you agree that user's should not be able to self-answer their own questions within a certain period of time?

Suppose that I ask a silly easy question, like

```
"In Java, how do I print 1 to 10?"
```

Then I may hurry and answer it myself, in order to game the system and get easy points.

What if we instituted an initial 12-hour "stand-by" period, whereby the user cannot self-answer.

If I ask something that I can self-answer within 12 hours, it seems obvious that I wasn't really stuck to begin with(and should rethink even asking it).

It was drawn to my mind by this post :

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Then I may hurry and answer it myself, in order to game the system and get easy points.

If the question (and the answer) is low-quality, then the posts will get downvotes so there are no easy points to get.

> If I ask something that I can self-answer within 12 hours, it seems obvious that I wasn't really stuck to begin with(and should rethink even asking it).

Self-answering to share your knowledge is allowed, it's even encouraged. So people should be able to answer their own question immediately if they want to share knowledge.